# Open large file without special software

Tags: windows, notepad

I have a large `.txt` file which I am trying to open. But the programs (Notepad, Notepad+, Adobe Dreamweaver, etc.) that I tried all tell me that it is too big. The size of the file is ~1.6 GB.

Is there a way to open this file locally without installing a special software?

Comment: Also, what OS is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use WordPad

```
WordPad will open any text file no matter the size. However, it has limited capabilities as compared to a text editor.
```

And in the comments of that post

```
I just used WordPad to open a 1.2G file that Notepad++ couldn't.
```

[Source and suggestions for programs which should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208524/how-to-read-text-file-of-about-2-gb)

As an aside I've also had luck with Notepad++

Comment: WordPad failed for me on a 16GB text file.

Comment: Sure I guess it would fail on 16gb but given the user wanted 10% of that file size i don't think it matters?